# Derandomizing arbitrary width *read-many* and *ordered* branching programs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomness, derandomization, space-bounded, pseudorandom-generators

**Modifying following TedP**

We know that derandomizing width $5\leq k\in O(1)$ read many branching programs is equivalent to $BPNC^1=NC^1$ and derandomizing width $k\in\Omega(n)$ read once ordered branching programs is equivalent to $BPLP=L$ where $BPLP$ is class programs which are in two sided error based randomized logarithmic space and terminate in deterministic polynomial time.

> What are derandomizing width $k=f(n)$ two-sided error 1) read many with $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ and 2) read once ordered with $f(n)\in o(n)$ randomized branching programs equivalent to?

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted, but maybe the wording could be clarified to explain what "derandomizing X is equivalent to [equivalence of two classes]" means.  Does "derandomizing X" mean that randomized branching programs with X decide the same languages as deterministic branching programs with X?

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this as an answer because I am unable to comment.) There may be some confusion between models here. Width 5 *read many* branching programs capture $NC_1$, and width poly$(n)$ *ordered* branching programs (a subset of read-once branching programs where the input variables are read in a known fixed order) capture the behavior of a logspace machine over its random bits (so an optimal PRG for such implies $BPL=L$). There is extensive work on derandomizing small-width ordered BPs, and in some restricted classes we have near-optimal constructions (for large error).

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, TedP! What do you mean with "ordered branching programs capture ... a logspace machine"? We have $\text{Logspace}_{/poly}=\text{BP}$  where $\text{BP}$ is the class of polynomial-width polynomial-depth read-many Branching Programs. The restriction of read-once is non-trivial. For example, a Logspace machine can compute the Hidden Weighted Bit function, but an ordered read-once branching program cannot. So In that sense, ordered read-once BPs capture only a strict subset of logspace machines.

Comment: O(1) width read many bp is NC1 while poly (n) width read many bp is L/poly. Thank you and these are the kind of classifications I was looking for.

Comment: Since the question might be wrongly framed can you make the updates necessary to correct the BPLP part?